# httplog isn't logging any request made by Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

I am debugging my Rails app that makes weird requests (2 instead of just 1 request).

I am using gem called `httplog`. I added it in Gemfile then executed `bundle install` .

After that I required httplog after my net/http gem.

```
 require 'net/http'
 require 'json'  # => false
 require 'httplog' # require this *after* your HTTP gem of choice
```

Then I restarted my app and tried to make request from my app.  My POST request executed but I didn't see anything from `httplog`.

**My log:**

```
Started GET "/users/auth/yandex/callback?state=b618f2a61ce3ce6b7a5xxxxxx2dd9755a3f9ec728b52ad959&code=32xxxx" for 212.3.194.120 at 2017-04-23 22:12:20 +0300
Processing by CallbacksController#yandex as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"b618f2a61ce3ce6b7a5xxxxxx2dd9755a3f9ec728b52ad959", "code"=>"32xxxx"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`provider` = 'yandex' AND `users`.`uid` = '455934123'  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'xxxxx@yandex.ru' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `provider`, `uid`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2017-04-23 22:12:21', 'xxxx@yandex.ru', '$2a$10$.hZf/TKkqxxxxlNz6iuSMUiIdG1SAqg5KyXEaImAoHiNFNVJqS', 'yandex', '455934123', '2017-04-23 22:12:21')[0m
  [1m[35m (6.7ms)[0m  COMMIT
response   === {"error_description": "Code has expired", "error": "invalid_grant"} 2017-04-23 22:12:21 +0300
  [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  UPDATE `users` SET `expires_in` = '2017-04-23 22:12:21', `updated_at` = '2017-04-23 22:12:21' WHERE `users`.`id` = 7
  [1m[36m (2.8ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE `users` SET `current_sign_in_at` = '2017-04-23 22:12:21', `current_sign_in_ip` = '212.3.194.120', `last_sign_in_at` = '2017-04-23 22:12:21', `last_sign_in_ip` = '212.3.194.120', `sign_in_count` = 1, `updated_at` = '2017-04-23 22:12:21' WHERE `users`.`id` = 7[0m
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://xxxxx.ngrok.io/ru
Completed 302 Found in 424ms (ActiveRecord: 13.9ms)
```

**Note**: In above log file `response   === {"error_description": "Code has expired", "error": "invalid_grant"} 2017-04-23 22:12:21 +0300` is a response to my POST request made by my application.

I believe it should have some type off HTTPLOG ?

**What I have tried:**

I added this line in `environments/development.rb`

```
HttpLog.configure do |config|
 config.logger = Rails.logger
 config.color = {color: :black, background: :light_red}
end
```

Then restarted server. But upon new start of server I received error:

```
config/environments/development.rb:44:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for HttpLog:Module (NoMethodError)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Thank You!

Comment: Hi @Edgars, I'm the author of httplog. To your second question, you probably just need to upgrade httplog to the latest version - the `configure do` syntax is relatively new. To your original question, if it's still relevant, please post your full Gemfile and a snippet of the code that makes the HTTP request you expect to see in the logfile. Thanks!